# How to get the table-name and database-name in the CDC event received from debezium kafka connect

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

**Setup:** I have CDC enabled on MS SQL Server and the CDC events are fed to Kafka using debezium kafka connect(source). Also more than one table CDC events are routed to a single topic in Kafka.

**Question:** Since I have more than one table data in the kafka topic, I would like to have the table name and the database name in the CDC data.

I am getting the table name and database name in MySQL CDC but not in MS SQL CDC.

Below is the Debezium source connector for the SQL Server

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{
  "name": "cdc-user_profile-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "<<hostname>>",
    "database.port": "<<port>>",
    "database.user": "<<username>>",
    "database.password": "<<password>>",
    "database.server.name": "test",
    "database.dbname": "testDb",
    "table.whitelist": "schema01.table1,schema01.table2",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "digital.user_profile.schema.audit",
    "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": true,
    "include.schema.changes": false,
    "event.deserialization.failure.handling.mode": "fail",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial_schema_only",
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
    "transforms":"addStaticField,topicRoute",
    "transforms.addStaticField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.addStaticField.static.field":"source_system",
    "transforms.addStaticField.static.value":"source_system_1",
    "transforms.topicRoute.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.topicRoute.regex":"(.*)",
    "transforms.topicRoute.replacement":"digital.user_profile",
    "errors.tolerance": "none",
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true,
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": 60000,
    "errors.retry.timeout": 300000
  }
}'
```

I am getting the below output (Demo data)

```
{
  "before": {
    "profile_id": 147,
    "email_address": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  "after": {
    "profile_id": 147,
    "email_address": "test_modified@gmail.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "version": "0.9.4.Final",
    "connector": "sqlserver",
    "name": "test",
    "ts_ms": 1556723528917,
    "change_lsn": "0007cbe5:0000b98c:0002",
    "commit_lsn": "0007cbe5:0000b98c:0003",
    "snapshot": false
  },
  "op": "u",
  "ts_ms": 1556748731417,
  "source_system": "source_system_1"
}
```

My requirement is to get as below

```
{
  "before": {
    "profile_id": 147,
    "email_address": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  "after": {
    "profile_id": 147,
    "email_address": "test_modified@gmail.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "version": "0.9.4.Final",
    "connector": "sqlserver",
    "name": "test",
    "ts_ms": 1556723528917,
    "change_lsn": "0007cbe5:0000b98c:0002",
    "commit_lsn": "0007cbe5:0000b98c:0003",
    "snapshot": false,
    "db": "testDb",
    "table": "table1/table2"
  },
  "op": "u",
  "ts_ms": 1556748731417,
  "source_system": "source_system_1"
}
```

Comment: You could make one connector per table, then add `static.field` to add in the table.

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 ,this would be the best workaround till https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-875 is rolled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is planned as a part of https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-875 issue

Comment: Thanks @jiri , when will this feature be rolled out.

Comment: Right in the next release - I estimate in 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Debezium Kafka-Connect generally puts data from each table in a separate topic and the topic name is of the format hostname.database.table. We generally use the topic name to distinguish between the source table & database name.

If you are putting the data from all the tables manually into one topic then you might have to add the table and database name manually as well.

Comment: How would i add it manually in CDC event ?.The reason for adding more than one table data to kafka topic is because this is an enterprise datapipeline and there might be 100s of tables. If we keep increasing the topics like that then performance of the kafka cluster will deteriorate. Also kafka connect provides this feature via setting these two properties CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_KEY_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy".